# Gmail API limits

Tags: android, gmail

When an app is granted permission by the user to access their Gmail account and the app makes calls such as sending e-mail, is there a limit on the number of API calls that can be made by the app or is the limit based upon the number of times the API is accessed via the user's account?

For example, if my app is being run by 1 million users and the number of API calls is limited by Google to 100,000, does that mean that as soon as 100,000 API calls has been reached regardless which device makes those calls and regardless whose account the token is associated with, my app will not be able to make any further API calls for the remainder of the day?

Or does it mean that 100,000 API calls may be made from a single device from my app running on that device but limits it to the account that granted permission to use the Gmail service?

What I need to avoid is Google limiting my app suddenly when 1,000,000 API calls from diverse devices and accounts is made to the Gmail service. If Google limits my app this way, I'm better off to not use the Gmail API and simply revert to using the typical SMTP and POP services where the user must enter their username/password.

The following is documented by Google:

> The upload rate is one API request - per second - per user, no matter
>   how many threads are making upload requests.

Taken from [Google Apps Email Settings API Limits and Quotas](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/email-settings/limits)

but there is no clear definition by what is meant by "per user". Account? IP address? Client ID???

Answer (score 0):

You wrote *When an app is granted permission by the user to access their Gmail account* and then ask the definition of *user*. I think they are the same. A *user* is the end-user, sending emails, and identified by it's email address.